# JQuery button effect without default button layout

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add the jquery button effect to links for mouse hover only and without the default button layout.

I created [this js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daliaessam/6yn3c75m/).

Here is the code I started with:

```
<div class="ui-widget ui-widget-content" style="border: 0px;">
    <a href="#" class="buttonize">Register</a>
    <a href="#" class="buttonize">Login</a>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.buttonize').button()
                .removeClass('ui-state-default')
                .css({'font-weight': 'normal', 'border': '0'});
});
```

First, is there a better way for doing this using default jquery ui themes because I am bound to use them not my css.

Second, if the button text default is normal and the ui theme has bold font in the ui-state-hover the link extends larger when hovering which moves all the other elements on the page, so the question how to detect if the link font is normal and not bold then remove the bold effect when the hover.

I created another [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daliaessam/vmzhzpy9/) with what I came up with :

The current code as a jquery plugin to buttonize links is:

```
$('.buttonize').each(function(){
    $(this).button();
    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-default');
    $(this).css({'border': '0'});
    var fontWeight = $(this).css('font-weight');
    if (!(fontWeight == 'bold' || fontWeight == '700')) {
        $(this).css({'font-weight': 'normal'});
    }
});
```

Comment: It isn't clear why you are applying the jQuery UI Button widget when it appears you don't actually want a button?  Why not use spams or divs and add a click handler?

Comment: I want the same hover effect of the button.